# Exact steps needed to migrate a react native android app to iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I've written a react-native app and compiled it for android.
Now I wish to compile my app for iOS.
I've searched the internet and found a lot of documentation about adding react-native components to an existing iOS app project, but couldn't find a concrete guide/explanation on how to take an existing react-native project(with many components, packages installed etc) and add the relevant iOS configuration.

I guess that I somehow should create an iOS project through xCode,then probably copy some project files into my ios folder of my project, create a podfile corresponding to my packages in package.json, install the required stuff using pod install and then maybe I can run it using the react-native run-ios command, but I'm really not sure whether I'm correct and to do these steps.

If someone can clarify to me what are the required steps I'll be grateful! (And I think other people might find it useful as well)

Comment: Full disclosure: I really don't know.   Android: yes.  IOS: No :(  STRONG SUGGESTION: 1) Set up an XCode development environment for yourself and successfully create, build and deploy a react-native "hello world" app.  2) Import your existing (Android) react-native project into Xcode.  3) See how far you get.  4) Post back questions about specific probems.

Comment: @FoggyDay Thanks. As I mentioned in my question, I saw some guides on how to add react-native components to existing iOS projects, but I'm not really sure how to merge a whole react-native project into an existing one (step 3 in your explanation). Also, I'm not really sure if that's the correct way to do it, so I asked here in case someone can describe a more detailed explanation.